# PHP hide divs on specific pages

Tags: php, html, show-hide

Already searched all topics regarding this question but none of the answers helped me so I'm posting a new question.

I have my page index.php which has php include that all navigation links open in the same index.php. For example when I click about us it opens index.php?page=aboutus.

My problem is I have a div on my homepage:

```
<div class="icons_small"> 
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/facebook_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/twitter_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/youtube_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/location_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
</div>
```

For this div, I want him to be hidden in index.php but I want it to be visible on all other pages like index.php?page=aboutus, index.php?page=contact etc.

Is there any simple way to do this with php? :)

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If the GET parameter `page` isn't set or doesn't have a value, it will hide the div.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] != "") {
?>
<div class="icons_small"> 
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/facebook_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/twitter_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/youtube_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/layout/location_icon_s.png" width="75" height="67" /></a>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: No problem. If my answer has solved your problem, choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on how the pages are being included.

If we are using PHP's `echo` to print out the HTML, we could simply choose to not print that specific section out with `echo` when page is not set (that is, there is no `page=whatever`).

```
if(!isset($_GET['page'])
{
    echo 'The contents of the div that shouldn't be on the page';
}
```

If for whatever reason you cannot selectively print sections, a *messy* alternative would be to echo some JavaScript which would remove the div. However, this has the crucial flaw that the div would still be shown for users who have JavaScript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is not secure at all. I understand it's all about 4 images but learning from a bad practice could be fatal for other projects.

What would happen if I write `"index.php?page=I_WANT_TO_SEE_THAT_BOX"` ?

What I would suggest is, check should you display it or not directly in your including function. I assume you have something like

```
function IncludeView() {
  $allowed_pages = array("view","friends","foo","bar");
  if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if(in_array($_GET['page'],$allowed_pages)) {
      include_once(PAGE_DIR."/".$_GET['page'].".php");  
      define("IS_PAGE_OKAY",true);
    }
  }
  else header(BASE_URL);
}
IncludeView();
```

Later in your template:

```
<?php if(defined("IS_PAGE_OKAY")) { ?>
   //your html code that is shown only on other pages than index.php
<?php } ?>
```